# Angular 2 - Component property undefined in method

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a property that is a custom class array.  The array is populated with a call to a service which calls a web service for data.  I have subscribed to the observable and I'm using the complete event to fire off a method which loads a graph.

The data the graph uses should come from the array which is populated during the subscribe, but when I attempt to do so in the method I am getting an undefined error on my component property.  Why is this the case, I though that the component property should be accessible to methods in the same class.

```
export class MetricsComponent implements OnInit{
errorMessage: string;
metric: MetricData[] = [];

//constructor is used for dependency injection
constructor(public _metricsService: MetricsService){}

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('talking to service...');
    this._metricsService.getData()
        .subscribe(
            data => this.metric = data,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
            this.LoadChart
        );  
}

LoadChart(): void {
    console.log(this.metric);  // <== this returns as undefined
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use arrow functions to retain the scope of `this.`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('talking to service...');
    this._metricsService.getData()
        .subscribe(
            data => this.metric = data,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
            () => this.LoadChart()
        );  
}
```

Comment: to build on this more specifically why it works is the third argument in .subscribe() is the onComplete function which will be called when the Observable is 'complete'.

Comment: Ok, that worked, now I have a new issue that is similar.  I have a setInterval function inside the LoadChart method, how would I get the 'this' inside that?

Comment: It's the same `setInterval(() => doSomething())`

Comment: Thanks again Günter!

Answer (score 0):

do it like this for more info read about [`lexical this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) and `arrow functions` one more thing if you are using chrome developer tools it will still show null there is some bug with chrome developer tools.

```
LoadChart = () => void {
    console.log(this.metric);  //
}
```

Comment: Thanks for going more in depth and providing the link to Lexical this.